# How to replace characters from one file with characters from another

Tags: c#, string

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string words = "U:\\words.txt";
        Console.WriteLine("The words are:");
        string[] listofwords = File.ReadAllLines(@words);
        for (int i = 0; i < listofwords.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listofwords[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        string clues = "U:\\clues.txt";
        Console.WriteLine("The clues are:");
        string[] listofclues = File.ReadAllLines(@clues);
        for (int i = 0; i < listofclues.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listofclues[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I want to use the clues file to replace words in the words file how and honestly I do not want to hard code them in sois it possible to retrieve single characters from a file and replace them with single characters from another file. And if yes how?

Comment: sure the contents are as follows:

Comment: the clues are A#
M*
N%

Comment: the words are : 1.#+/084&"
 2.#3*#%#+
 3.8%203:
 4.,1$&
 5.!-*%
 6..#7&33&
 7.#*#71%
 8.&-&641'2
 9.#))85
 10.9&330*

Comment: ignore the first number and . but anything else is one of the words but number 6 has 2 dots in front one in to show its a word the other is acctually part of the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just a straight swap? For example, the first word in the clues file replaces the first word in the words file? If not, how do you know which word in the clues file is going to replace which word in the words file?

Here's an example of a one-for-one replacement of the words.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] words = new string[] { "WordOne", "WordTwo", "WordThree", "WordFour" };
        string[] clues = new string[] { "ClueOne", "ClueTwo", "ClueThree", "ClueFour" };

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current word is " + word);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (string clue in clues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current clue is " + clue);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < clues.Length; j++)
            {
                words[i] = words[i].Replace(words[i], clues[j]);
            }
        }

        foreach (string newWord in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New Word is now " + newWord);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, the hard-coded words were to give you a fully working example. Use your file loading code to open the words.txt and clues.txt and then my code to manipulate them.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may have a clues.txt looks like this:
Key Value
Apple Banana
Cherry Dog

Where you replace Key with Value such as: Apple with Banana and Cherry with Dog.
If that's the case, you can hash all the Keys in the clues file, then save in a key-value list with their corresponding Values, then go through the words.txt, and for each word in the file, hash it and try to find in the key-value list, if it exists, output its Value, otherwise, output the original word.